# How to process text and grab text from hash c#

Tags: c#

In my program i wan to run my InputPass.text through:

```
static string Hash(string input)
{
    using (SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
    {
        var hash = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
        var sb = new StringBuilder(hash.Length * 2);

        foreach (byte b in hash)
        {
            sb.Append(b.ToString("X2"));
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

How do i put text into it and grab out the result to be put into my string hash pass. im having trouble understanding its process and would like to understand it as well. The hashed pass is what i am looking to instantly hash to be stored in an xml document for a local users file.

Comment: And what's the problem? The code is right there.

Comment: "How do i put text into it and grab out the result to be put into my string hash pass." By calling the function, like `string hashedPass = Hash(inputPass.Text);`?

Comment: But when i do that the result that is returned is empty?

Comment: You don't actually mean `string hashedPass = Hash(InputPass.text);`, do you?

Comment: Works fine for me. "Hello World!" returns 2EF7BDE608CE5404E97D5F042F95F89F1C232871.
See this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gG2dhL

Comment: `string hashedPassword = Hash(InputPass.Text)`? It's unclear what exactly you're asking. Also, don't simply SHA1-hash passwords, that's not secure.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the parameter you give the function as parameter is null or empty.
You can debug it and look at the variable or you can check with

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(<your_string>)
```

Comment: Yes, the string was null, changing it to a unity UI text solved the problem. thank you!